# 500 internal server error - php

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am running the 1 website on my server. That website has a search facility.

When I search for a category named "apple" at that time its showing 10 results and I am getting search result page fine and fast. `[RECORDS ARE PAGINATED 10 records per page]`

Now, When I search for "orange" named category at that time its giving me an internal server 500 error. It's just because it's trying to pull 300000 records from the database. `[After 2 mins I am getting this error on page]`

So How can I resolve this issue? I have checked queries too and its all fine. I need to record faster with no errors like internal server.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Please help! Thank you....

Comment: use index for your tables

Comment: check your error logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` in your database queries to get only the number of rows you need, for example this will select the first 10 rows :

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE something = "something" LIMIT 10
```

And you can also use an offset, this will select 10 rows from the 5th row :

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE something = "something" LIMIT 5,10
```

More information in the official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

If you need the total number of rows you can use [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "table" WHERE something = "something"
```

Comment: I already did limit. but On result page I also needs to show how many results found in total and also I needs to show per category howmany records are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your information in another table or field and actualize it on inserting and deleting items 
or 
if you don't want to change your code, you can implement a cron job, that will actualize it in an interval of time.